# Multiple functions in setState callback doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code where I want to execute 2 functions after the state is updated:

```
var stateCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state)
this.setState(stateCopy, () => {
   this.calculatePoints();
   this.generateLink();
})
```

However only the last function is executed. Does someone know what I'm doing wrong? Could it be because both of those functions are changing the state and only the state from the lats function is actually saved? In that case, how exactly would I solve it if I need both functions to update state?

Comment: What is 'stateCopy'?

Comment: post the code of those functions, please

Comment: @kinduser Oh I'm sorry I forgot to include that line, I have updated the code.@unknown They are basically updating values in the state, is it still relevant to post?

Comment: Why would you call state update even if you are not changing anything inside it?

Comment: @kinduser I am making a copy of the state, making changes to the copy and then updating the state by passing in the copy to setState.

Comment: Are you sure you want to create a copy of the state? Keep on mind that `Object.assign` doesn't deeply clone any object, maybe it would be better to use immutable functions instead?

Comment: @kinduser Yeah I'm still pretty new to React and the `Object.assign` has worked just fine for multiple projects so far.

Comment: Okey so lets back to your main problem, are you sure that `calculatePoints` isnt called? Have you thrown a console.log function inside it to check whether its called?

Comment: @kinduser I checked and both functions are called, however only the state from the last function is saved. If I remove `setState` from `generateLink` then the state from `calculatePoints` is saved and if I add back `setState` to `generateLink` then the state from `calculatePoints` is simply ignored like `calculatePoints` was never called.

Comment: Consider showing us your both nested functions

Comment: You should update state in one place to avoid this problem. I also wonder about the validity of doing shallow copy and overwriting the whole state with it. Instead do setState({stateCopy: stateCopy}) to store the copy in its own property.